# Is it possible to use the built in chart animations in excel when updating source data for charts?

Tags: excel, vba

When I change the source data in excel the pie chart I am using has a nice, fluid animation to represent the updated value(s). However, when I update the same value(s) via a VBA macro it doesn't animate at all and just snaps to the updated chart.

Is it possible to retain this fluid animation feature when updating chart data with VBA code?

The version of excel I'm using is Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14729.20312) 64-bit in case it's relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Application.EnableMacroAnimations = True` ?

From the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.application.enablemacroanimations) , it's set to `False` by default.